# Can you redirect STDERR for an entire Bash session?

Tags: bash, stderr

There are lots of questions regarding redirecting `stderr` and `stdout` for a single command or script.  What I'd like is to redirect any stderr messages from my Bash session to a log file.

I'd like an interactive bash session where all `stderr` is redirected to a file.

Comment: Are you looking for `exec 2>file`?

Comment: That's going to hide the prompt/etc. though as well since that uses `stderr` too.

Comment: @EtanReisner tbh, I don't really understand the question… (there's a lot of noise in this question and the information needed to answer is not clearly stated)

Comment: OP, you know, we don't care that you're running a demo. We don't care that it does some non-standard stuff with regards to network socket communication. Maybe also, we don't care that you're doing that through `ssh`. Don't add too much noise to your question (by the middle of the second paragraph I wanted to close the tab). So: you want an interactive Bash session where `stderr` is redirected to a file? if that's the case, cut all the useless stuff, and only include this information.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf `by the middle of the second paragraph I wanted to close the tab` The questions 8 lines,chill out.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I cleaned up the question.

Comment: @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９ Well, look at the question now: only one line, with only the information we need.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf 3*. Suprised you weren't complaining about the first redundant line still.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A horrible way to deal with your problem:

```
exec 3>&2
trap 'exec 2>>/path/to/your_file' DEBUG
PROMPT_COMMAND='exec 2>&3'
```

- `exec 3>&2`: we first copy fd 2 to a new fd (here fd 3)
- `trap 'exec 2>/dev/null' DEBUG`: Before each command is executed (and if the shell option `extdebug` is set, which is the default in interactive shells), the `DEBUG` trap is executed: here we redirect `stderr` to the file `/path/to/your_file` (make sure you give an absolute path).
- Before each prompt is displayed, Bash executes the string in the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable: here we redirect fd2 to fd3 (and fd3 was a copy of fd2 when it pointed to the terminal). This is necessary to print the prompt.

I wouldn't qualify this as a robust or nice method, yet it might do the job for your purpose.

Comment: Whatever gets the job done is cool with me.  Works like a charm!

Comment: Sometimes hacks are the only ways to get the job done +1

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

```
exec 2> elsewhere
```

or redirect the invoking command.

Comment: This won't work well for an interactive shell session, though. The prompt is written to standard error; user input is echoed to standard error as well.

Answer (score -4):

Not an exact answer but this is what I use. It will display STDERR on the screen and log all of STDOUT and STDERR to a log:

```
eval $1 2>&1 >>~/max.log | tee --append ~/bash.log
```

Comment: It is hard to imagine a context in which `eval $1` is what you want. Perhaps you meant `eval "$1"`, although that is also highly questionable.